# codemirror data cannot be serialized without the submit event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, form-submit, codemirror, jquery-click-event

I have this problem with [codemirror](http://codemirror.net/) which is quite tricky and I have no idea how to get around to it.

The data from codemirror just won't be serialized without the **submit event** - that's what I found out so far - like this below,

```
$(':submit').submit_form();

(function($){
    $.fn.extend({ 
        submit_form: function(options) {

            var defaults = {
            }

            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
            var o = options;

            var $cm = this.click(function(e){

                var form = $(this).closest('form');
                alert(form.serialize()); // the textarea field with codemirror returns empty

                $.post(form.attr('action'),form.serialize(),function(xml)
                {
                   ...
                   ...
                }
            });



        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

html,

```
<textarea name="code_1" id="code_1" title="EMBED CODE" class="editor-codemirror" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
```

I have to change this line

```
var $cm = this.click(function(e){
```

to

```
var $cm = this.submit(function(e){
```

then the data in the codemirror can be serialised.

but I have to attach the plugin to the **click button** first and find its **closest** form and **serialise** its form data before `ajax post`. So I must use click event to trace the **closest** form.

I wonder if anyone has come across this problem before and what is the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the `save` method. http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#save